# Android - Java generic SpinnerAdapter

Tags: android, generics, spinner

I am searching a way to do this :

```
public class SimpleText_SpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Enum1> {
   many lines of code with a one moment : String val = oneEnum1val_inparam.getlabel();
}

public class SimpleText_SpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Enum2> {
   exactly the same code than previously, but for Enum2
}

public class SimpleText_SpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Enum3> {
   exactly the same code than previously, but for Enum3
}
```

This is made to have 3 adapters for 3 spinners, that contains values from 3 differents Enums constructed exactly the same way but with different values.

Of course, each enum type has a getLabel() method.

I'd like to find a way to do this without needing to copy-paste 3 times the same code for each adapter. A sort of generic one, that could be referenced by 3 specialized one.

I don't find the solution.
Could you help me to do this ?

Or if you have somthing more efficient...

Oliver

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
public class SimpleText_SpinnerAdapter<T extends Enum<T> & ProvidesLabel>
    extends ArrayAdapter<T>
{
    // implementation
}



public enum Enum1 implements ProvidesLabel
{
        Entry1("label 1"),
        Entry2("label 2");

    private final String label;

    private Enum1(String label)
    {
        this.label = label;
    }

    @Override 
    public String getLabel()
    {
        return this.label;
    }
}

public interface ProvidesLabel
{
    String getLabel();
}
```

Instantiate class with (nm the constructor):

```
 SimpleText_SpinnerAdapter<Enum1> enum1 =
        new SimpleText_SpinnerAdapter<Enum1>(context, textViewResourceId);
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! It works like a charm. What a crazy kind of code

Comment: If I can ask and take a litlle bit of your time, what does that mean : 
public class SimpleText_SpinnerAdapter<T extends Enum<T> & ProvidesLabel>  extends ArrayAdapter<T>

<T extends Enum<T> & ProvidesLabel>, waow, I'm not sure to understand  :-)

Comment: No problems. It means that SimpleText_SpinnerAdapter will operate on a type (T) which extends the Enum class and (&) it must also implement the interface ProvidesLabel. The now defined type <T> is then passed on to the ArrayAdapter in the extends clause.

Comment: I think most of us find java generics a little confusing in the beginning (the syntax, especially with enums, doesn't help); have a look at http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html - it explains generics from the beginning. They're a very powerful tool once understood.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I love this programming language :-)

Comment: Glad I could be of service ;). PS. When you think a question has been satisfactorily answered, you should mark the answer in question as "answered".